# C++ include error: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, sfml

I am using the SFML library to try and build a game (it's my first time so I'm really struggling). I have given an include path in the `tasks.json` file and `c_cpp_properties.json` file but still when I build it, it finds an error in the model.cpp file, saying 'No such file or directory' regarding the `#include <SFML\Window.hpp>` line. The code of my files are shown below:

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "CUSTOM C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-I C:\\Users\\MY_NAME\\Desktop\\projects\\asteroids-game\\include",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**c_cpp_properties**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Users\\MY_NAME\\Desktop\\projects\\asteroids-game\\include",
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**model.cpp**

```
// std libs
#include <iostream>

// SFML libs
#include <SFML\Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The exact directory (copy-pasted from file explorer) where the header file is stored is:

```
C:\Users\MY_NAME\Desktop\projects\asteroids-game\include\SFML
```

Surely the include path given in the tasks.json file, and the include line from model.cpp would point it to this location?

This is the error it gives me in the VS Code terminal:

```
C:\Users\wswil\Desktop\projects\asteroids-game\src\model\model.cpp:7:10: fatal error: SFML\Window.hpp: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <SFML\Window.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: And where are you specifying where `<SFML\Window.hpp>` should be looked up by the compiler? Search where's that file placed at your computer, and add a directory relative to that path to your include directory flags.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think that's what I've done. Just above where I've shown the error I'm receiving, I've pasted in the directory that it should be looking at for the header file. I've given "-I C:\\Users\\MY_NAME\\Desktop\\projects\\asteroids-game\\include" as the include path in the tasks.json file and from here, the #include in model.cpp should look in the SFML directory for Window.hpp. The include directory flags are what I have given in tasks.json file right?

Comment: So you're telling that `C:\\Users\\MY_NAME\\Desktop\\projects\\asteroids-game\\include` has a subdirectory `SFML` containing that header file referenced? Sounds like a strange Installation setup for the SFML libraries, but well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes I moved it into that directory so everything was contained within the project. I know its not conventional and I'll probably change it back to a standard installation path but it helped initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was a very stupid error and I've just fixed it.

In the `tasks.json` file, the include directory had a space between `-I` and the file directory path:

```
"-I C:\\Users\\wswil\\Desktop\\projects\\asteroids-game\\include"
```

While trying to learn how to set everything up, I read that you can have the space or not, it won't make a difference. I added it in so it was easier to read but turns out this is incorrect. There cannot be a space or it won't read the file directory.

Hopefully someone else sees this and can fix their own issue! thanks for any helpful comments too.